# Cash on delivery: Pending Invoice

Tags: invoice, payment, ee-1.13

We are using the payment method Cashondelivery.

When creating an invoice in the backend, there is no option to select "pending payment". The invoice is created always as paid.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this in EE, but in CE you could try the following:

Go to

```
app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cashondelivery.php
```

and copy this file to the `/local/` codepool.

Open this duplicate file and find this code, it's almost at the top

```
    /**
     * Payment method code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code  = 'cashondelivery';
```

Now add the folowing line of code

```
    protected $_canCapture = true;
```

It should now say

```
    /**
     * Payment method code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code  = 'cashondelivery';
    protected $_canCapture = true;
```

Now save the file, flush all cache and when creating the invoice you should now see a drop down box in the right bottom corner, like this.

[image]

You can now select **"Not Capture"** and create the invoice. The invoice status should be "pending". Once you have received the payment you can set the invoice to complete by using the **"Capture"** button.

Reference: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.nl/2010/04/how-to-change-invoice-status-in-admin.html